# How to get filter weights after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to see what values filter has adopted after training? If after the training loop I mention filter.eval() will it get me the values of filter weights that the filter has adopted after complete training? I don't think so I can get the filter weights in this way because filter variable calling a function weight_variable which is picking some values from normal distribution. I think calling filter.eval() command after training loop is simply like printing filter before training. So how can I get the values of filter weights that filter has adopted after training?

```
`def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
#network
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 
FLAGS.image_height*FLAGS.image_width])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])



input=tf.reshape(x, 
    [-1,FLAGS.image_height,FLAGS.image_width,FLAGS.input_channel])
filter = weight_variable([FLAGS.filter_size, FLAGS.filter_size, 
    FLAGS.input_channel, FLAGS.filter_channel])
conv_out = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(input, filter))

pool_out = max_pool(conv_out)


pool_list = pool_out.get_shape().as_list()
input_dim = pool_list[1]* pool_list[2]* pool_list[3]
pool_2D = tf.reshape(pool_out, [-1, input_dim])
W_fc = weight_variable([input_dim, 2])

logits = tf.matmul(pool_2D, W_fc)   #(batch_size,2)
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(logits)`
```

## after checking correct predictions apply training loop

```
`
for i in range(max.training_step):
    #Check training and test accuracy
print(filter.eval())`
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you use the same graph and session. Graph contains the setup of your model and session contains the values of all the weights in the model. If you don't use the same graph/session you will not get the same weights. I think in your example you use some default graph and session. It should work but it's better if you are more explicit about them.

It looks like `filter` should be a tensor. If you do `print(filter)` you should see something like `<tensor object shape=(..) >`. In this case `print(filter.eval())` will return you the correct weights.

If not, you can use the graph to get the tensor. `graph.get_tensor_by_name('filter_weights:0')` will give you a tensor that you can look at. You can get the name from tensorboard (from the graph) or you can run `tf.trainable_variables()` to get a list of all the variables defined in the graph (and pick the one you want).

An alternative to `filter.eval()` is to do `session.run(filter)`. They are equivalent.

Comment: I am using tf.InteractiveSession.  When you say that you need to use same graph and session what does in mean?

Comment: Should I have to explicitly mention tf.Graph? In my code I haven't mentioned this command anywhere